# Teamforge to Gforge repository migration from database

Tags: svn, gforge, teamforge

I am trying to migrate some 300+ projects from Teamforge to Gforge. Rest all parts worked fine but Source code migration from Teamforge SVN to Gforge is not working out.

The structure in Teamforge is there are multiple repositories in  a single project while I can't find any such option in Gforge.

While I am copying all folders in Gforge */data/repo/svnroot*. The structure is coming good for a single repository but how do we take care of multiple repositories in Gforge.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the late response, but S/O didn't notify me about this posting until just today.

I'm assuming that you are using GForge AS 6.4.4. GForge doesn't currently support multiple SCM repositories per project, but it is on our roadmap.  The easiest workaround for now is to create a separate project for each repository, and then make those projects *children* of the main project.

Each child project will show up in the "Project Hierarchy" on the parent project's home page, and the parent project will likewise be shown in the same section for each child project.

You can also turn off all plugins except SCM for the child projects, and this will make the menu for each much simpler and straightforward for users.

We would be happy to work with you on the migration.  You can contact us by submitting a [Free Support](https://next.gforge.com/#/project/gforge5/trackeritem/add?tracker=10345) ticket.

Please also take the time to look at [GForge Next](https://gforge.com/products), our ground-up rewrite of the 6.4 product - it's 100% compatible (no migration), [installs using Docker in 60 seconds](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i2WNQaJbc0U), and we can even help you run both old and new versions at the same time, on the same database.

Cheers!

Michael Tutty, CTO at GForge

Comment: Thanks. This helps. Have another query on attachments migration. Have raised the ticket on the portal you mentioned.

Comment: Yup, we saw it.  You should hear from Tony (GForge CEO) to set you up temporarily with support.